# Getting NZEC error for python:

Tags: python, runtime, runtime-error

I am a newbie in python, started learning the language a week ago tried to test it out in codechef...

Here is the question link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/COOMILK

So with what i understood so far i typed the following piece of code..

```
t=int(input())
f=[]
if(t >= 1 and t <= 50):
  for each in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    if(n >= 1 and n <=50):
      m=input().split()
      for i in range(len(m)):
        if(m[i]=='milk'):
          q=1
        elif(len(m)==1 and m[0]=='cookie'):
          q=0
          break
        elif(m[i]=='cookie' and m[i+1]!='milk'):
          q=0
          break
      f.append(q)
  for i in f:
    if(i==1):
      print("YES")
    elif(i==0):
      print("NO")
```

So apart from the n constraint being not checked during the input, what actually showed was a runtime error.
New to this can someone explain it clearly why i am getting the nzec error?
Compiled it on my own and for all the test cases it worked properly but does not compile on code chef.. any help would be appreciated.

**What i have gathered from the net is that there is no raw_input in python 3.x that i am using currently, so just a friendly reminder here....**

Answer (score 1):

NZEC stands for "Non Zero Exit Code". It occurs when you encounter a runtime error usually index out of bound error.

There is a mistake in the 14th line of your code:

```
elif (m[i]=='cookie' and m[i+1]!='milk'):
```

what if i+1 is out of range?
e.g.,
Consider the input to be:

1

3

cookie milk cookie

- 1 is the number of testcases.
- 3 is the number of elements in the
  list.
- 'cookie milk cookie' composes the list elements.

When the value of i is 2 and your code's 14th line comes to execution, it will generate an index out of bound error(because m[i+1] i.e. m[3] doesn't exist!) which is a type of runtime error and thus generates NZEC error.

Add this code after the 7th line of your code:

```
if m[-1]=='cookie':
    f.append(0)
    continue
```

Comment: So how to improve the code?, i know the basics of c/c++ but dunno how to implement it in python... Just as you know, i am in the process of understanding this language. BTW thanks for the reply.

Comment: First things first, you dont thank for an answer, you upvote an answer! I've edited my answer to get rid of NZEC!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
try:
  #working code
except Exception:
   pass
```

Try and catch exception for java code.